# Differentiability in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $U\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, and let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$, and let $a\in U$. Let $\|\cdot\|'$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\|\cdot\|''$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$. 
Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if it satisfies the definition of 
differentiability at $a$ with $\|\cdot\|'$ and $\|\cdot\|''$ substituted for the Euclidean
norms (on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, respectively).

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on this particular problem? Do you know the theorem about the equivalence of norms in finite dimensions? What is your definition of differentiability at the point $a$ with your norm $||\cdot||'$ and $||\cdot||''$?

Comment: I am not sure about the definition of differentiability at the the tow norm. I know about differentiability but not sure about norm space.

Comment: If you're not sure please write what you think is the correct definition, someone will tell you if you're right or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate consequence of the fact all norm in $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent.